# Simulate left click on cursor position in Swift Xcode

Tags: swift, macos

I'm Trying to Simulate a left click in Swift Xcode.
I've found this code online but it moves the cursour, Is there a way to keep the cursor in it's current spot and click?

```
import Foundation

let source = CGEventSource.init(stateID: .hidSystemState)
let position = CGPoint(x: 75, y: 100)
let eventDown = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: source, mouseType: .leftMouseDown, mouseCursorPosition: position , mouseButton: .left)
let eventUp = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: source, mouseType: .leftMouseUp, mouseCursorPosition: position , mouseButton: .left)


eventDown?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)

//eventDown?.postToPid(71028)
usleep(500_000)
//eventUp?.postToPid(71028)
eventUp?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem in your current code is the following line :

```
let position = CGPoint(x: 75, y: 100)
```

You clearly assign a new position to your mouse cursor.
You should use the `mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream`, like this :

```
let position = self.window.mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream as CGPoint
```

Be aware that this returns a NSPoint that you may have to cast as a `CGPoint` (like I did).

As you are working with a Playground, here is a much detailed sample :

```
import Cocoa
import PlaygroundSupport

// You need to create a view to provide to your current PlaygroundPage
let currentView = NSView()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = currentView

// Here you are able to get your cursor current location
let cursorPosition = currentView.window!.mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream as CGPoint

// Then you are able to run your code below using the cursorPosition variable
let source = CGEventSource.init(stateID: .hidSystemState)
let eventDown = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: source, mouseType: .leftMouseDown, mouseCursorPosition: cursorPosition , mouseButton: .left)
let eventUp = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: source, mouseType: .leftMouseUp, mouseCursorPosition: cursorPosition , mouseButton: .left)


eventDown?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)

//eventDown?.postToPid(71028)
usleep(500_000)
//eventUp?.postToPid(71028)
eventUp?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
```

Comment: Would you mind showing me how to implement this in my current code?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Of course, I think you only have to replace your `let position = CGPoint(x: 75, y: 100)`
with mine (sorry, I will edit as I named it `location` instead of `position` like you did). I think this will do the trick, but I haven't tested it in a playground to be honest

Comment: I've applied the change to my code but I'm getting the error: Cannot find 'self' in scope.

Comment: Oh, indeed, are you working with a Playground here ? Or in a single-file script without any class ? (self is used when you use a class or an object, here you don't)

If you are working with a Playground, there are several imports to do to get the current window, just tell me and I will update my answer :)

Comment: I've edited my answer above to a full detailed example, this should work the way you wanted to

Answer (score 0):

You should disable application sandboxing in order to make your code work